# Combine inner join result to one column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have one shop table and one item table. Shop table has many item, and my problem is I want to search multiple items that available in one shop.

```
shop table
id | name
---------
1  | Shop 1
2  | Shop 2

Item table
id | name    | shop_id
----------------------
1  | JRC     | 1
2  | sukhoy  | 1
3  | sukhoy  | 2
```

When I want to find item jrc and sukhoy, so it must showing Shop 1, because both two items are ready on Shop 1.

My expected output is

```
Output table
id | shopName | itemName
------------------------
1  | Shop 1   | JRC
2  | Shop 1   | sukhoy
```

My query is

```
select * from shops
inner join products as produk2 on produk2.shopId = shops.id and (produk2.name like "%sukhoy%")
inner join products as produk on produk.shopId = shops.id and (produk.name like "%jrc%")
```

It works because it using different alias per inner join. 
But what I want is, how to combine the output from that 2 join without define different alias. Or how I can combine join result into one same column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select p.shop_id
from products p
group by p.shop_id
having sum(p.name like '%jrc%') > 0 and
       sum(p.name like '%sukhoy%') > 0;
```

This returns shop ids that have both products.  Of course, you can join the results to `shops` to get more information about the shops.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one join:

```
select * from shops
inner join products as produk 
on produk.shopId = shops.id 
and (produk.name like "%jrc%" OR produk.name like "%sukhoy%")
```

Comment: hmm I don't think it works that way, it must be both item in one shop. Your query return even just one item in one shop